# Combining Rows of Lists in Column containing Integers with Python

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the most Pythonic way to work with lists containing integers within a pandas dataframe as below? My first objective is to just retrieve a list of all unique values in all of the lists across all of the rows.

```
index   col1                                                                                                                                     
54      [53, 31, 20, 33, 54, 191, 172, 112, 42, 61, 57]  
55      [53, 31, 201, 9, 30, 21, 50, 113, 26, 39, 40, 59]  
57      [34, 201, 37, 35, 21, 40, 163, 179, 1]
```

I have tried `apply(lambda x: set(x))` but it only works on individual lists as opposed to the entire column.

Just adding some progress I've made that is so very close and I completely forgot you can just add lists together to combine the numbers. Here is what I did I would consider very pythonic. :

```
list(set(df1['col1'][0] + df1['col'][1]))
```

which gets me a nice combined set of unique values but now I have to figure out how to add every single row with one another. such as `df1['col1'][0] + df1['col1'][1]+...+df1['col1'][n]`.

Trying list comprehension which is getting me a combined collection of the lists but trying to wrangle it to look like the output from the set method above.

```
[(df1['col1'][x]) for x in range(len(df1))]
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not at all sure what you mean. If you can provide an example, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use itertools.chain to combine the lists - I think this would be the most pythonic solution.

```
from itertools import chain
set(chain.from_iterable(df1['col1']))
```

Comment: this is the second time this month that itertools has saved the day for me. Thank you so much. This did the trick beautifully.